# Windows - Crawl URL and grab links

Tags: windows, download, search, website, web-crawler

I have recently signed up to a large video site as a premium member and I want to generate a list of the video files on the site so that I can put them into my download manager and download the premium videos to my harddrive in one go.

I have been playing around with blackwidow and havent had any luck. I have also been playing around with "linkchecker" but it doesnt support password restricted sites.

Can anyone tell me how I can put in something like:

> members.site.com

and have it crawl all the links in the site and give me a list of the ones with conform to the following filter:

> FullHigh-1.mp4

The full path to the videos seems to be something like this:

> members.site.com/cdn_video.php?path=name/dir/videos/example-mp4FullHigh-1.mp4

I would like to make the point that this is NOT against their T&C's, I already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Windows version of wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) which is an extremely versatile web crawler and downloader.

If you don't like the idea of using the command line then [WinWGet](http://www.cybershade.us/winwget/) gives you a GUI.